# PHP $_FILES array remains empty after file upload

Tags: php, forms, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-server

I have spent hours trying solve this issue but nothing worked. I am trying to upload a csv file of size 0.5 kb.

This is my html form:

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The $_FILES array remains empty after submit:

```php
var_dump($_FILES); // array(0) { }
```

The $_POST array receives the name of the csv file:

```php
var_dump($_POST); // array(1) { ["file"]=> string(11) "numbers.csv" }
```

From the `php.ini` file: (bottom two are commented out in the file)

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20

;upload_tmp_dir =
;sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```

Perms on `/var/tmp` folder (if relevant)

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096
```

Comment: Inspect the request in your browser, make sure it is not modified by scripts/extensions.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought it would be some problem with the DOM. Turns out I was using nested form tags, which is illegal in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad I wasn't aware that my form tag is enclosed inside another form tag.

Not allowed:

```html
<form>
    <form>
    </form>
</form>
```